# Is it possible to right-align the second line inside a "split" environment inside an "align" environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, alignment

When breaking a long equation over exactly two lines, the `multiline` allows doing so without adding spurious equation numbering and without manually placing `\notag` tags. It also right-aligns the second line.

When needing such a line break inside an `align` environment, a nested `split` environment can be used. But when using this to introduce a line-break into the right-hand side of the equation, it will be left-aligned.

Manually aligning the equation with `\phantom{}`,`\hspace{}` and `\qquad` constructs is doable, but results in less readable and less maintainable source code, so I want to avoid it at least until final editing.

Is there any way to get it right-aligned instead? Is `split` even the correct environment for this usecase?

### MWE

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\textwidth = 10cm
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  The =& First Equation Is Short Enough For One Line
  \\
  \begin{split}
    The =& Second Equation Is So Long That Splitting It
    \\   & Over Two Lines Is Desirable
  \end{split}
\end{align}
\begin{multline}
  But = How Do I get The Second Line To Be
  \\    Right-Aligned Like For A Multiline?
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

### Example from real-world document

[image]

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{fouriernc}
  \begin{document}

  \begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
  \Delta_1B(t)
  &=
  \sum_{\alpha}
  F_\alpha e^{-i\omega_\alpha t}
  \sum_{ij}
  -\frac{
    f_{ij} B_{ij} A^\alpha_{ji}
  }{
    \hbar(\omega_{ij}+\overline\omega_\alpha)
  }
  \\
  \begin{split}
  \Delta_2 B(t)
  &=
  \sum_{\alpha\beta} 
  F_\alpha F_\beta e^{-i(\omega_\alpha+\omega_\beta)t}
  \sum_{ijk}
  \Bigg(
  \frac{
    f_{ik} B_{ij} A^\alpha_{jk} A^{\beta}_{ki}
  }{
    \hbar^2
    (\omega_{ki}-\overline\omega_\beta)
    (\omega_{ji}-\overline\omega_\alpha-\overline\omega_\beta)
  }
  \\&
  +
  \frac{
    f_{jk} B_{ij} A^\beta_{jk} A^{\alpha}_{ki}
  }{
    \hbar^2
    (\omega_{jk}-\overline\omega_{\beta})
    (\omega_{ji}-\overline\omega_\alpha-\overline\omega_\beta)
  }
  \Bigg)
  \end{split}
  \end{align}
  \end{subequations}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: what about  the`multilined` environment from the `mathtools` package? it is intended for nesting in math environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest a pretty hacky way with `multlined` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\Delta_1B(t)
&=
\sum_{\alpha}
F_\alpha e^{-i\omega_\alpha t}
\sum_{ij}
-\frac{
  f_{ij} B_{ij} A^\alpha_{ji}
}{
  \hbar(\omega_{ij}+\overline\omega_\alpha)
}
\\
&\begin{multlined}
\mathllap{\Delta_2 B(t)}
=
\sum_{\alpha\beta} 
F_\alpha F_\beta e^{-i(\omega_\alpha+\omega_\beta)t}
\sum_{ijk}
\Bigg(
\frac{
  f_{ik} B_{ij} A^\alpha_{jk} A^{\beta}_{ki}
}{
  \hbar^2
  (\omega_{ki}-\overline\omega_\beta)
  (\omega_{ji}-\overline\omega_\alpha-\overline\omega_\beta)
}
\\
+
\frac{
  f_{jk} B_{ij} A^\beta_{jk} A^{\alpha}_{ki}
}{
  \hbar^2
  (\omega_{jk}-\overline\omega_{\beta})
  (\omega_{ji}-\overline\omega_\alpha-\overline\omega_\beta)
}
\Bigg)
\end{multlined}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Notice that you can't place `&` inside `multlined`, so in order to align on the equal sign, you'll have to pretend that `\Delta_2 B(t)` has zero width. Hence `\mathllap` (again, from `mathtools`).

The result looks fine to me:

[image]

Comment: The `multlined` environment does exactly what I want, but I found that you use it unnecessarily complicated :) Rather than the `\mathllap` construct, I just put `B_2(t) &=` to the left of the `multlined`, and used `\begin{multlined}[t]` for the correct vertical alignment.

Comment: In that case the equation label also moves up. I'm not sure it's correct to label the first line of the multiline equation if the label is placed to the right.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the number to be on the first line or on the last line. Whether this is "correct" is ultimately decided by the style guide / copy-editor, if any. Looking at the papers around me, centering it seems to be a common convention, when a group of equation has a single number. I somehow can't find any Journal-published right now, that use `align`-style multiple equations...

Comment: As far as I know, the common convention in this case is to number the first line if numbers are on the left margin, and the last line if they are on the right margin. Unfortunately, the `tbtags` option doesn't work for `multlined`, but `\begin{multlined}[b]...\end{multlined}` lowers the number.

Answer (score 1):

Exploiting the fact that the two left-hand sides have the same width, you can use `aligned` for the second equation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
&\Delta_1B(t)
=
\sum_{\alpha}
F_\alpha e^{-i\omega_\alpha t}
\sum_{ij}
-\frac{
  f_{ij} B_{ij} A^\alpha_{ji}
}{
  \hbar(\omega_{ij}+\overline\omega_\alpha)
}
\\
&\begin{aligned}
\Delta_2 B(t)
=
\sum_{\alpha\beta} 
F_\alpha F_\beta e^{-i(\omega_\alpha+\omega_\beta)t}
\sum_{ijk}
\Biggl(
\frac{
  f_{ik} B_{ij} A^\alpha_{jk} A^{\beta}_{ki}
}{
  \hbar^2
  (\omega_{ki}-\overline\omega_\beta)
  (\omega_{ji}-\overline\omega_\alpha-\overline\omega_\beta)
}
\\
+
\frac{
  f_{jk} B_{ij} A^\beta_{jk} A^{\alpha}_{ki}
}{
  \hbar^2
  (\omega_{jk}-\overline\omega_{\beta})
  (\omega_{ji}-\overline\omega_\alpha-\overline\omega_\beta)
}
\Biggr)
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\Bigg` is not the right command; you should distinguish between `\Biggl` and `\Biggr`, in order that the spacings are right.

[image]